# Append all rows from one table to another using Pytables

Tags: python, database, hdf5, pytables

Let's take for example the following:

```
import tables
import numpy as np

# Two Example Tables
hfile = tables.open_file('myfile.h5', 'a')
data1 = np.ones((3, 2))
data1.dtype = [('a', float), ('b', float)]
data2 = np.zeros((3, 2))
data2.dtype = [('a', float), ('b', float)]

table1 = hfile.create_table(where='/', name='table1', obj=data1)
table2 = hfile.create_table(where='/', name='table2', obj=data2)

# Appending
table1.append(table2.read())
table2.remove()

hfile.flush()
hfile.close()
```

Is there a better way to do this on-disk?

One solution is to iterate through rows:

```
for r in table2.iterrows():
    table1.append([r[:]])
```

The latter seems to bulky and the former draws the whole second table into memory before appending. I'd rather do something like:

```
table2.append_where(dstTable=table1)
```

But this function only works with a condition so I would need one that always evaluates to true to get the whole table. Surely there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `append_where()` with a trivial condition like `'True'` probably is the best solution.

Comment: I tried to accomplish this with a trivial condition ('True') and received the following error:  `ValueError: there are no columns taking part in condition 'True' `

Comment: Hmm then you just need some trivial condition like `col1 == col1`, which works assuming that there is are no NaNs.  Or if there are NaNs, you can use `~(col1 != col1)`. This should be a feature PyTables has, though, would you mind submitting a feature request to the list or github?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/376) for PyTables to make the condition optional, as @jtorca requested. Given the [support voiced by one of the maintainers](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/376) it is likely to be accepted and included in a future version of PyTables.